# jQuery UI Sortable Draggable Iframe Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have one parent page with some items and I have another iframe page with sortable items. I want to drag the parent page item into the iframe page sortable item.

I have tried [jQuery Draggable Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) for this but it will not work properly with iframes. I have also tried with `iframeFix: true,` but it still will not work properly with iframes.

In the end I uses [this](http://dharmeshdhakan.com/examples/drag.html) example to do it. This example is exactly what I need. The only issue is that when you drag the element into the iframe page from the parent page, the element sticks at the end of the other elements, but I need to add the element on the particular position.

Comment: Updated Your [this] Link..